# sendBroadscast VS startActivity. What is the difference?

Tags: android

What is the differents between sendBroadcast (intent) to startActivity(intent).

Why this don't work:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
smsIntent.setData( Uri.parse( "sms:0533"));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");
sendBroadcast(smsIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sendBroadCast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) sends a global broadcast that is to be picked up by any `BroadcastReceivers` that are set to receive that broadcast.

[`startActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) attempts to start an Activity based on either the class name you specify **or** the Intent Action (which is a String).

In your case [`Intent.ACTION_SENDTO`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO) is an Intent Action and so, needs `startActivity()`

From the docs:

> Standard Activity Actions
>
> These are the current standard actions that Intent defines for
>   launching activities (usually through **startActivity(Intent)**. The most
>   important, and by far most frequently used, are ACTION_MAIN and
>   ACTION_EDIT.

Comment: @Amina no problem. Since this answer did clarify things, it would be appreciated if you'd mark it as accepted.