# android intent startActivity() and sendBroadcast()

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

What are the differences between startActivity() and sendBroadcast()?
We can use startActivity() to start a activity.sendBroadcast() can do this too.what are the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do look similar, cause they have same function: *send a message to receiver*.

**You can tell the difference from the receiver.**

startActivity() can only has one receiver, in other words, only one receiver can receiver it's message(intent).

But for sendBroadcast(), multiple receivers can receive the message.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go,

startActivity() - gets an intent and open its attached activity.
You have two ways how to use it - explicit - by adding activity name to the intent or implicit by adding only action(Ex. Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).

activity.sendBroadcast() - broadcast is a totally different thing than intent.
With broadcasts you can communicate with any registered broadcast receiver, in practice - sending messages to different component within/outside your application.

Answer (score 0):

[sendBroadCast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) sends a global broadcast that is to be picked up by any BroadcastReceivers that are set to receive that broadcast.

[startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) attempts to start an Activity based on either the class name you specify or the Intent Action (which is a String).

REF : [sendBroadscast VS startActivity. What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184220/sendbroadscast-vs-startactivity-what-is-the-difference)